# Rails concern how to call ClassMethods from InstanceMethod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

I need to call `weight_to_kg` **class method** from **instance method**.

I would like to create weight to kg converter for a lot of my models, that have weight column in pounds.

```
module WeightConvertor
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def weight_kg
    # I need to call weight_to_kg method
    ClassMethods.weight_to_kg(weight) # does not work
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def weight_to_kg(weight)
    end
  end
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WeightConvertor
  # weight column is present
end

Order.first.weight
Order.first.weight_kg
```

How can I do it?

Comment: self.class.name.constantize.weight_to_kg(weight) when call class method in instance method

Comment: Thanks! You are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self.class.weight_to_kg(weight)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be expressed more simply; I don't think you need more than 1 module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module WeightConverter

    LB_PER_KG = 2.20462262

    def weight_kg
        weight / LB_PER_KG
    end
end


class Order
    include WeightConverter
    attr_accessor :weight

    def initialize(weight)
        @weight = weight
    end
end

order = Order.new(22.0462262)
puts "Order weighs #{order.weight} lbs, which is #{order.weight_kg} kg."

# Output: Order weighs 22.0462262 lbs, which is 10.0 kg.
```